# Tag-score on profile page not updated

Tags: bug, tag-score, badge-progress

The next badge that I am tracking shows a tag-score, but this tag-score is not correctly updated when I refresh the profile page window.

When I go to settings the tag-score is (when I had additional upvotes in the meantime) not the same as on my profile page. When I click the same badge the view is updated and the score is correct...

Comment: @Thaillie Yep, I tend to agree even though from the title it is not that obvious...